# iCloud documents gone following update

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, data-synchronization

I'm on macOS 10.15 Dev Beta 8. iPad is running iOS 13 Dev Beta 8.

My documents folders (Keynote, Pages, iMovie, etc) in the root iCloud Drive folder are all missing. Usually I'd pencil it in as a delayed sync post-update, but I've checked my iPad and they're missing there too. iCloud.com shows the files being there, in the correct place.

Why would both my iPad and my Mac be missing the folders if iCloud.com seems to think they're there?

Does anyone have an experience like this?

Comment: What was the update?

Comment: @benwiggy the most recent developer seed, I've since unenrolled. Silly mistake, I know, but I'm just trying to figure out how that would explain the iPad.

Comment: So this is about the a beta seed?  Which one?  Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.  You'll need to [edit] your question to include the relevant info regarding version/build and hardware type.   Also, be sure you've opened a Feedback to Apple about this issue.

Comment: @fsb thanks for the help. I've updated to reflect the beta versions and I'll open a Feedback with Apple now.

Comment: I think you're out of luck to get these syncing again, at least until these OS's are released.  The iCloud sync issue in these betas was a widely reported problem as early as the first betas.  Some have had the syncing return with subsequent releases but if it hasn't happened to you yet then you might have to wait.

Comment: @fsb thanks to the advice, I wasn't aware of any issues with syncing issues in the betas. I'll wait and see, I suppose. Is there some way I can mark your comment as answered?

Comment: I didn't add it as an answer because I wasn't sure it was really answering your question.  I would recommend leaving it open for a few days in case someone has other info that would help you sync the iCloud docs.

Comment: Can happen on Mojave/Sierra non-beta upgrades, and on newer Betas. Just download them and it will not happen again (until maybe next upgrade). Or disable this feature. See my anwer below

Answer (score 1):

That is normal and documented by Apple. (yes it is a known bug, but you didn't lost anything. They were all moved to your iCloud under Documents and/or Desktop folders.

**You have to download them from iCloud again**

If you want to change settings:

Change this setting under System Preferences -> iCloud (save "Documents and Desktop" on iCloud.

[image]

but this "problem" of missing just happens on Upgrade. If you like you can continuing syncing Documents and Desktop to iCloud. It is just that you will have to download them at least once, now.